# Very basic question about regex extraction

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract an ID specified in URLs that have this structure:

```
https://trello.com/c/iGjJLqwr/1-test-project
```

in the above example I want to extract:

```
iGjJLqwr
```

I need to use the regex expression in Zapier that according to the documentation uses Python regex

The following Python regex somehow is in the right direction but it still returns too much:

```
[^https://trello.com/c/][\w]+
```

returns 3 matches:

```
Match 1
Full match  21-29   iGjJLqwr
Match 2
Full match  31-36   -test
Match 3
Full match  36-44   -project
```

I need to restrict the result to:

```
iGjJLqwr
```

The following regex returns an extra forward slash

```
[^https://trello.com/c/]\w+/

Match 1
Full match  21-30   iGjJLqwr/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets `[ ... ]` create a character set that selects *one* of any of the characters they contain. If a carat is added at the beginning, `[^ ... ]`, this set is negated. The pattern does not consider the full, continuous string within the brackets.

In other words, `[aaabbc]` is equivalent to `[abc]` (and even`[cba]`).

If you just want to capture the first path element after `https://trello.com/c/` in a group, you can use this pattern:

`https://trello\.com/c/([^/]+).*`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/99FDJS/2

If you want the pattern to only match this substring within the URL, you can use positive lookahead and lookbehind:

`(?<=https://trello\.com/c/).+?(?=/.*)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/99FDJS/1

Answer (score 0):

This will match the ID without the extra forward slash:

```
import re

string = 'https://trello.com/c/iGjJLqwr/1-test-project'

match = re.search(r'[^https://trello.com/c/]\w*(?=/)', string)

print(match.group(0))
```

```
iGjJLqwr
```

The `(?=/)` asserts that the next character is a forward slash.

Comment: The use of square brackets here is not working how you expect. Compare with `[^cmo:/.]\w*(?=/)` which will produce the same results.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks for pointing that out. I will note that this example should work for the purposes of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern you use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches only one out of several characters. Starting with a `^` will make it a [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) character class which matches any character that is not in the character class.

Since the character class is not followed by a quantifier, this `[^https://trello.com/c/]` will match a single `i` or `-` and then `\w+` will match 1+ times a word character.

That will give you the matches `iGjJLqwr`, `-test` and `-project`

I think you meant to match the id in a capturing group:

```
^https://trello\.com/c/(\w+)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG0d8H/1)

About the pattern

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `https://trello\.com/c/` Match literally `https://trello.com/c/`
- `(\w+)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ times a word character